# Ubuntu crashed for no apparent reason, unsure of how to get it back

Tags: dual-boot, data-recovery, crash

I am running the up-to-date version of Ubuntu, set up on an Acer 64 bit machine with a Kingston solid state hard drive, with a set-up that allows me to boot into either Ubuntu (where I do about 95% of work) or Windows 7. I've been running it this way for months without problems, and Ubuntu started freezing up, so I had to cold-boot the system. While I can boot into the Windows partition with no problem, when I attempt to boot into Ubuntu, I get the following:

```
mount: mounting /dev/disk/by-uuid/d6bd2da2-d626-499789c8-64efbf5d2853 on/root
failed: invalid argument
mount: mounting /dev on/root/dev failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /sys on/root/sys failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /proc on/root/proc failed: No such file or directory
Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init
No init found. Try passing init= bootarg

Busyboxv1.21.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.210-1ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)

Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

I don't know what's wrong or what to do from this point, and please bear in mind, when you give instructions, that I am a bit old and very ignorant of anything beyond the basics of using Ubuntu. Also, while I can access the files on the Windows partition from Ubuntu, I was wondering if there is any way I can recover the files saved in Ubuntu, should I have to reinstall. Whoever responds, thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Do you have backups of any documents (or settings) on the *Ubuntu* (Kingston) drive? Do you have the skills/confidence to run *Ubuntu from USB*, to examine the solid-state drive (and/or recover any data)? **EITHER of these elements is what is needed, to recover ..**

Comment: I've never done it, but I'm willing to give it a shot.

Comment: I just attempted running Ubuntu from the USB drive I originally used for installation, and it says it cannot access that partition, and that the partition is not mounted. Is there a way around this?

Comment: **First priority:** Check out the device hardware, if necessary using a trained technician. This may be electrical, or device failure. Do not *open the box* unless you understand the risks, and likely damage you could cause.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not a hardware problem, considering Windows boots & runs fine on the same drive. There are some Windows and linux tools to check a drive's SMART data that are an option too. But just in case I'd try **data recovery first** before doing any write tests to the drive.

When you boot from a live iso (USB/CD) if you can paste the mount errors (from the terminal, or probably in `/dev/log/syslog` too) that should help a lot.

Mounting read-only (`ro`) might allow access to copy off your data files at least, if you don't have a backup already.  This should work if you're booting live:

1. Find out which drive partition you'd like to mount (the `/dev/sdx#` name).  In a terminal, run (as root or with `sudo`) some of these to find out what device/partition (like `/dev/sda1`) you're after. The linux partitions are probably an ext3/4 format, windows usually NTFS:

   `lsblk` or `blkid` or `fdisk -l` or `parted -l`
2. Make a mountpoint `sudo mkdir /mountpoint` (for example, often the're in `/media/` somewhere, may work better in there).
3. Try mounting it read-only with the device & mountpoint from earlier

   `mount -o ro /dev/sdx# /mountpoint`

   **Watch for any error messages here**. If it mounted ok you should be able to read & copy your data from `/mountpoint`

It may need a filesystem check before it wants to mount (see `man fsck` & the other tools like `fsck.ext3`, `fsck.<morenames>`). But those could write to the filesystem, possibly overwriting your data you'd like to recover first, so that wouldn't be a *"best practice" of data recovery*.

If it wouldn't mount, other tools like `testdisk` or `photorec` could be used to try & read the data anyway. See this [Ubuntu Data recovery](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery) page, or the [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) or [photorec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) documentation/help for more info.

---

And with "mount: ... failed: invalid argument" you might want to take a look at your `/etc/fstab` file... maybe edit that into your Q?

Or a tool like [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) could help for GRUB boot problems, but that may not be the problem here (could even mess up Windows booting which still works now).